# react issues, nothing is loading when i add my header component to my home component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import { ChakraProvider, CSSReset } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Nav from './nav';
import Home from './components/home';
import Contact from './components/contact'
import Menu from './components/menu';
import About from './components/About';
import Reservations from './components/reservations';
import Header from './header';

function App() {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <CSSReset />
      <Router>
        <Nav/>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
          <Route path="/menu" component={Menu} />
          <Route path="/reservations" component={Reservations} />
       </Routes>
     </Router>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I want to be able to switch between the different pages and have different components run on each page however only the nav bar is available. I'm new to react so I'm not sure what the issue is

```jsx
import Header from '../header'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header/>
    </>
  )
}
```

```jsx
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: '#495e57', textAlign: 'center', padding: '20px' }}>
      {/* Centered Image */}
      <img
        src="little/src/pictures/small_logo.png"       
        alt="Centered"
        style={{ display: 'block', margin: '0 auto', height:'50px', width:'50px'}}
      />

      {/* Text Section */}
      <div style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}>
        <h1 style={{ color: 'blue' }}>Your Header Titl</h1>
        <p style={{ fontSize: '18px', color: 'green' }}>Your subheading or additional information goes here.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Box, Flex, Spacer, Link as ChakraLink, Text, Button } from '@chakra-ui/react';

const Nav = () => {
  return (
  <>
    <Box bg="black" p="4">
      <Flex>
        <Text fontSize="xl" fontWeight="bold" color="white">
          My Logo
        </Text>
        <Spacer />
        <Box>
          <ChakraLink as={Link} to="/" color="white" mx="2">
            Home
          </ChakraLink>
          <ChakraLink as={Link} to="/about" color="white" mx="2">
            About
          </ChakraLink>
          <ChakraLink as={Link} to="/contact" color="white" mx="2">
            Contact
          </ChakraLink>
          <ChakraLink as={Link} to="/menu" color="white" mx="2">
            Menu
             </ChakraLink>
             
            <ChakraLink as={Link} to="/reservations" color="white" mx="2">
            reservations
            </ChakraLink>
        </Box>

        <Button colorScheme="teal" ml="2">
          Sign In
        </Button>
      </Flex>
    </Box>

</>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

not sure where the issues lie im thinkinging it either has something to do with the router or the file structure

Comment: Which version of react-router-dom are you using? If v6 you should use either `element={<Home />}` or `Component={Home}`. See https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#elementcomponent. Take note of the warning... _"You should only opt into the Component API for data routes via RouterProvider"_

Comment: It seem to me that you followed a react router v5 - v5.1 tutorial but ended up installing v6 . In react router v6, it is `Component={Home}` (The C letter is capital), please change it, see if it works. And beside, there is no `exact` prop in v6 (You can read more here: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#relative-routes-and-links)
If this does work, I'll write a full answer.